# Replace everything after word given in the other column

Tags: r, stringr

I have a data frame which looks like this:

| String | Word |
| --- | --- |
| tasty red apple number 1 | apple |
| tasty red apple and banana | apple |
| tasty banana and apple and peach | apple |
| tasty banana and peach | banana |
| tasty peach and apple | peach |

I want to delete all the words after the word given in the column Word and leave the word.

| String | Word | After |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tasty red apple number 1 | apple | tasty red apple |
| tasty red apple and banana | apple | tasty red apple |
| tasty banana and apple and peach | apple | tasty banana and apple |
| tasty banana and peach | banana | tasty banana |
| tasty peach and apple | peach | tasty peach |

Does anybody knows how to do it?

```
string <- с("tasty red apple number 1", "tasty red apple and banana", "tasty banana and apple and peach", "tasty banana and peach", "tasty peach and apple")
word <- c("apple", "apple", "apple", "banana", "peach")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could capture the characters (`(...)`) till the 'Word' as a group and then use the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group in `replacement` (`str_replace`).  The `.*` signifies rest of the characters we are discarding.  `str_replace` is vectorized for replacement as well, so we don't need any loop

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(After = str_replace(String, sprintf("(.*%s).*", Word), "\\1"))
```

-output

```
                          String   Word                  After
1         tasty red apple number 1  apple        tasty red apple
2       tasty red apple and banana  apple        tasty red apple
3 tasty banana and apple and peach  apple tasty banana and apple
4           tasty banana and peach banana           tasty banana
5            tasty peach and apple  peach            tasty peach
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(String = c("tasty red apple number 1",
 "tasty red apple and banana", 
"tasty banana and apple and peach", "tasty banana and peach", 
"tasty peach and apple"), Word = c("apple", "apple", "apple", 
"banana", "peach")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lookbehind with `gsub` in `mapply` to delete unwanted part of string.

```
transform(dat, After=mapply(\(x, y) gsub(sprintf('(?<=%s).*',  x), '', y, perl=TRUE), Word, String))
#                             String   Word                  After
# 1         tasty red apple number 1  apple        tasty red apple
# 2       tasty red apple and banana  apple        tasty red apple
# 3 tasty banana and apple and peach  apple tasty banana and apple
# 4           tasty banana and peach banana           tasty banana
# 5            tasty peach and apple  peach            tasty peach
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(String = c("tasty red apple number 1", "tasty red apple and banana", 
"tasty banana and apple and peach", "tasty banana and peach", 
"tasty peach and apple"), Word = c("apple", "apple", "apple", 
"banana", "peach")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(After = str_replace(String, str_c("(.*\\b", Word, "\\b).*"), "\\1"))
                            String   Word                  After
1         tasty red apple number 1  apple        tasty red apple
2       tasty red apple and banana  apple        tasty red apple
3 tasty banana and apple and peach  apple tasty banana and apple
4           tasty banana and peach banana           tasty banana
5            tasty peach and apple  peach            tasty peach
```

Here we (i) wrap `Word` into word boundaries `\\b` to prevent that larger words containing a `Word` value (e.g., "dapple"  and "apple") get matched. Then (ii) we wrap parentheses around that substring to coerce it into a capturing group, which we then (iii) refer to in the `str_replace` replacement argument, whereas anything that follows the capture group (`.*`) gets omitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `str_extract` instead of `str_replace` for a slightly simpler syntax:

```
df1 |>
  mutate(After = str_extract(String, str_c(".*\\b", Word, "\\b")))
```